# Adding razor views to NET Core Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2017

I am building an app .NET Core Api + Angular app that requires send emails to their users. The feature is working okay using html templates  and an ugly code to replace the conent in these files (there are at least 4 html templates). Now I want to do the thing better and I want to use razor views as my "mail templates" and I am following the article [here](https://scottsauber.com/2018/07/07/walkthrough-creating-an-html-email-template-with-razor-and-razor-class-libraries-and-rendering-it-from-a-net-standard-class-library/)

Basically the code is using  3 projects: razor pages / standard libray /Razor class library but in my case I only want add these "cshtml" files all inside of my api project. So that I did was create a folder Views and inside of it all the required razor views. After that I published these razor views to test if the project this kind of project understand that it must move the folder and files to the final destination BUT nothing happen.

Also I did some litle changes in my StartUp class in order to inform to VS that this project is also supporting MVC

ConfigureServices method:

```
   services.AddMvc(config => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
```

Configure Method:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

After these change nothing happen. What is missing?
Update 1: I found this useful link about [razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and as far I understand Razor files are compiled at both build and publish time and there isn't a way to check that razor files were copied correctly to output folder.

Comment: if you don't post your code in plaintext, it won't be indexable by search engines, which kind of beats the purpose of the website..

Answer (score 0):

try this startup class

```
public class Startup

{   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
        services.AddMvc(config => {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
       });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles(); //this middleware also should be added to the pipeline if your template has images,css etc.
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();  
    }
}
```